# Can I add a debug script to NPM?

Tags: node.js, npm

I have edited my package.json to customize the "start" script so it adds the --debug flag to node:

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node --debug server.js"
  }
```

Is there a way of adding new scripts for example a debug script that would do what my customized "start" is doing right now?

I'm looking to be able to execute:

```
npm debug
```

Answer (score 113, accepted):

In your package.json define the script

```
"scripts": {
  "debug": "node --inspect server.js"
}
```

And then you can use npm's run-script

```
npm run-script debug
```

or the shorter version

```
npm run debug
```

Comment: DeprecationWarning: `node --debug` and `node --debug-brk` are invalid. Please use `node --inspect` or `node --inspect-brk` instead.

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/nodejs-debugging#_auto-attach

Answer (score 20):

VS Code adds a <kbd>debug</kbd> button inline in the `package.json` file

1. **Open `package.json` and click debug above `scripts` section**

   [image: code npm package debug]
2. **Select script to debug**

   [image: code npm package debug options]
3. **Debugger should be attached**

   [image: code debugger]

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/nodejs-debugging#_auto-attach

Answer (score 16):

From the nodejs [docs](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/debugging-getting-started/#legacy-debugger):

> The legacy debugger has been deprecated as of Node 7.7.0. Please use --inspect and Inspector instead.

So starting from Node 7.7.0v use `--inspect`

Answer (score 3):

1. In VS Code hit cmd+shift+p (or View > Command Palette...)
2. Type `npm` and select `Debug: Debug npm Script`
3. Hit enter and pick the script that you want from the `scripts` of `package.json`.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

for remote debug
get npm-cli.js path

```sh
> npm --verbose
npm info it worked if it ends with ok
npm verb cli [
npm verb cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
npm verb cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
npm verb cli   '--verbose'
npm verb cli ]
npm info using npm@6.14.14
npm info using node@v14.17.5
```

then

```sh
node --inspect-brk "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" run your-npm-script
```

for mac or linux

```sh
➜  ~ npm --verbose
npm info it worked if it ends with ok
npm verb cli [
npm verb cli   '/usr/local/Cellar/node@14/14.18.2/bin/node',
npm verb cli   '/usr/local/bin/npm',
npm verb cli   '--verbose'
npm verb cli ]
npm info using npm@6.14.15
npm info using node@v14.18.2
```

```sh
node --inspect-brk "/usr/local/bin/npm" run your-npm-script
```