# How do I run javascript tests using debugger; statements?

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, debugging, testing

There doesn't seem to be a universal answer for this, nor is it asked on Stack Overflow. I come from a Python background where I can use `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` in my code and immediately walk through code using a debugger. How can I do this in NodeJS?

For instance, I'm trying to run and debug tests in [Browserify Shim](https://github.com/thlorenz/browserify-shim). This uses npm's [tap testing framework](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tap). To run the tests, I need to run `npm run test-main` from Browserify-shim's root directory.

If I add a `debugger;` statement in the code or the tests, nothing happens. I've tried running `npm run test-main --debug` as well as `npm run test-main --debug-brk` to no avail.

What is the correct way to effectively step through code in NodeJS?

Comment: Not sure if [this](https://nodejs.org/api/debugger.html) helps

Comment: @JaromandaX that's what I want to use. How can I use that in this scenario? If I add that in a browser it works as expected. I want this to work from the command line while running a test like it would using Python.

Comment: it's not as simple as adding `debugger` in the code - you have to start node with the debug option

Comment: @JaromandaX yeah that's what I'm asking how do I do that in a situation like this?

Comment: forgive my ignorance - does http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9633280/can-i-add-a-debug-script-to-npm help?

Comment: Not at all, thank you for helping! I actually saw that answer first which is why I tried `npm run test-main --debug` but it doesn't seem to work...

Comment: `npm run test-main --debug` looks nothing like `npm run-script debug` in the accepted answer - I must admit I'm a NPM noob when it comes to package.json though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer by realizing that the tap test runner isn't the only way to run the tests.

To solve, first I installed [Iron-node](http://s-a.github.io/iron-node/):

```
npm install -g iron-node
```

Then, for any test I want to run in debug mode I use `iron-node /path/to/test.js` and that steps me into a devtools debugging session in the browser.