# How do I create a custom command to replace `gulp` or `npm run`?

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp, gulp-sass, package.json

How can I write my own terminal commands for an NPM project, which would replace the `gulp` command without relying on `npm run`?

My project contains the following [Gulp](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp) and [http-server](https://github.com/indexzero/http-server) custom commands...

```bsh
## COMMANDS I CURRENTLY HAVE
|        Command        |            Task             |
|-----------------------|-----------------------------|
|      npm run boom     | "Builds then watches files" |
| npm run boom -- build |  "Builds the assets files"  |
|    npm run launch     |   "Starts a local server"   |
```

This is because of the `scripts` in its `package.json` file...

```js
/// package.json
{
  "scripts": {
    "boom": "gulp",
    "launch": "http-server -o"
  },
    "devDependencies": {
      "gulp": "^3.9.0",
      "gulp-sass": "^2.1.0",
      "http-server": "^0.8.5"
    }
}
```

Here is what I would actually like my custom commands to be...

```bsh
## COMMANDS I WANT TO HAVE
|   Command   |            Task             |
|-------------|-----------------------------|
|    boom     | "Builds then watches files" |
| boom build  |  "Builds the assets files"  |
| boom launch |   "Starts a local server"   |
```

#### EDIT

"[Can I add a debug script to NPM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9633280/can-i-add-a-debug-script-to-npm)" is *not* the same as what I am asking.  I've already defined scripts in my `package.json` file, which is how I ended up with my current commands.  What I want is to write my own project commands/scripts that do the same things as what I have listed, without having to type `npm run`.

*Example*

- **I Currently Have**

  - `npm run boom` command
- **What Does it Do?**

  - runs `gulp` command
- **What Command Do I Want Available in the Project Instead, That Does the Same Thing?**

  - `boom` command

Comment: I'm not sure about doing this in npm, but depending on your OS, you can add custom commands to run via command prompt/terminal.

Comment: @ItsGreg – I could make alias for it, which would apply to my command prompt, but I want these commands to work locally for anyone who decides to use the project.

Comment: There is no "simple" way to do it. You will have to create a npm package and put your commands under it, then install it as any other package. [This link give details](http://javascriptplayground.com/blog/2015/03/node-command-line-tool/) on the approach.

Comment: other example https://developer.atlassian.com/blog/2015/11/scripting-with-node/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I usually do this by writing a small CLI using [commander](https://www.npmjs.com/package/commander) then adding a `bin` entry into the `package.json` pointing to the CLI file.

```
    {
      ...
      "author": "",
      "license": "ISC",
      "bin":{
        "boom": "boom-cli.js"
      ...
    }
```

Then running either `npm install -g` or `npm link -g` from the root of the project.

If I recall correctly, `npm link -g` creates a symlink between your package and wherever your globally installed npm packages are kept which is preferable for me since I like to change things frequently.

[This](https://developer.atlassian.com/blog/2015/11/scripting-with-node/) is a good resource on the topic.

Answer (score 0):

Running `npm install` only did not help me. Need to run `npm link` which helped me run the CLI command.

Where `npm link` creates alias like below in the output: 
Example :
`$LOCAL_DIR\cli-command -> $LOCAL_DIR\npm\node_modules\$PROJECT\dist\index.js`
...